# Upload multiple images to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

i build a chat application using firebase and i want to send multiple image to firebase storage.

using this library

compile 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:3474549'

At the top

```
private StorageReference storageRef;
private FirebaseApp app;
private FirebaseStorage storage;
```

onCreate()Method

```
app = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
storage =FirebaseStorage.getInstance(app);
```

button click action

```
   Gallary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, AlbumSelectActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_LIMIT, 10);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE);
                pwindo1.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Activity result

```
    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(images));
        storageRef = storage.getReference("photos");
        final StorageReference photoRef = storageRef.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        photoRef.putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        String content = downloadUrl.toString();
                        if (content.length() > 0) {
                            editWriteMessage.setText("");
                            Message newMessage = new Message();
                            newMessage.text = content;
                            newMessage.idSender = StaticConfig.UID;
                            newMessage.idReceiver = roomId;
                            newMessage.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("message/" + roomId).push().setValue(newMessage);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: i cant upload any images.StorageException has occurred

Comment: Please edit your question with the stack trace, which you can get from logcat.

Comment: HEADS UP EVERYONE, the usage of `getDownloadUrl` under the `TaskSnapshot` object is no longer valid. It now belongs to the `DocumentReference` instance which was used to upload the file in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is working fine.

```
 if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
        Uri[] uri=new Uri[images.size()];
        for (int i =0 ; i < images.size(); i++) {
            uri[i] = Uri.parse("file://"+images.get(i).path);
            storageRef = storage.getReference("photos");
            final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child(uri[i].getLastPathSegment());
            ref.putFile(uri[i])
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            String content = downloadUrl.toString();
                            if (content.length() > 0) {
                                editWriteMessage.setText("");
                                Message newMessage = new Message();
                                newMessage.text = content;
                                newMessage.idSender = StaticConfig.UID;
                                newMessage.idReceiver = roomId;
                                newMessage.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("message/" + roomId).push().setValue(newMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution

Answer (score 7):

*Variables*

- private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
- Button chooserBtn, uploaderBtn;
- TextView alert;
- private Uri ImageUri;
- ArrayList ImageList = new ArrayList();
- private int upload_count = 0;
- private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
- ArrayList urlStrings;

*onCreate()*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uploaderBtn = findViewById(R.id.uploader);
    chooserBtn = findViewById(R.id.chooser);
    alert = findViewById(R.id.alert);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Images please Wait.........!!!!!!");
    chooserBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);


        }
    });
```

*Uploader Button*

```
    uploaderBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            urlStrings = new ArrayList<>();
            progressDialog.show();
            alert.setText("If Loading Takes to long press button again");
            StorageReference ImageFolder = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ImageFolder");

            for (upload_count = 0; upload_count < ImageList.size(); upload_count++) {

                Uri IndividualImage = ImageList.get(upload_count);
                final StorageReference ImageName = ImageFolder.child("Images" + IndividualImage.getLastPathSegment());

                ImageName.putFile(IndividualImage).addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                ImageName.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(
                                        new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                urlStrings.add(String.valueOf(uri));



                                                if (urlStrings.size() == ImageList.size()){
                                                    storeLink(urlStrings);
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
                                );
                            }
                        }
                );


            }


        }
    });


}
```

## This Line of will help us to store Links of All Images under One Node

```
                                                if (urlStrings.size() == ImageList.size()){
                                                    storeLink(urlStrings);
                                                }
```

*Store Links To Firebase Realtime Database*

```
private void storeLink(ArrayList<String> urlStrings) {

    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i <urlStrings.size() ; i++) {
        hashMap.put("ImgLink"+i, urlStrings.get(i));

    }
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");

    databaseReference.push().setValue(hashMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Uplosded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    alert.setText("Uploaded Successfully");
    uploaderBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    ImageList.clear();
}
```

*onActivityResult()*

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            if (data.getClipData() != null) {

                int countClipData = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                int currentImageSlect = 0;

                while (currentImageSlect < countClipData) {

                    ImageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(currentImageSlect).getUri();
                    ImageList.add(ImageUri);
                    currentImageSlect = currentImageSlect + 1;
                }

                alert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                alert.setText("You have selected" + ImageList.size() + "Images");
                chooserBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select Multiple Images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

This utility class I create it to upload multiple images to firebase storage using kotlin with help of coroutine. if you have any enhancement please tell me.

you need to add these dependencies firstly.

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:19.1.1'

//Firebase adds support to Coroutines through the kotlinx-coroutines-play-serviceslibrary

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.1"

for more info check [link](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-kotlin-coroutines-with-firebase-6f8577a3e00f), [github link](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services)

```
object FirebaseUtils {

    suspend fun uploadPhotos(photosUri: ArrayList<File>): List<PhotoUrl> {
        val storageRef = Firebase.storage.reference
        val photosUrls = ArrayList<PhotoUrl>()
        val uploadedPhotosUriLink = withContext(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).coroutineContext) {
            (photosUri.indices).map { index ->
                async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    uploadPhoto(storageRef, photosUri[index])
                }
            }
        }.awaitAll()

        uploadedPhotosUriLink.forEach { photoUriLink -> photosUrls.add(PhotoUrl(photoUriLink.toString())) }
        return photosUrls
    }


    private suspend fun uploadPhoto(storageRef: StorageReference, photoFile: File): Uri {
        val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val fileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)

        return storageRef.child(fileName)
            .putFile(fileUri)
            .await()
            .storage
            .downloadUrl
            .await()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For return list imageUrls with **same order** of images selected from gallery
don't use for loop for every uri

after you get `ArrayList<Uri> imageUriList` and you want now upload it to firebase storage then return the list of url for every image in same order your selected it, so i use **recursion** on below method until upload all uri

```
 private void uploadImages(@NonNull ArrayList<String> imagesUrl,ArrayList<Uri> imageUriList) {

        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Products").child(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        Uri uri = imageUriList.get(imagesUrl.size());


        storageReference
                .putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot ->
                storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    String url = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).toString();

                    imagesUrl.add(url);

                    //if same size so all image is uploaded, then sent list of url to to some method 
                    if(imagesUrl .size()  == imageUriList.size()){
                        allImageUploadedNow(imagesUrl);
                    }else {
                        uploadImages(imagesUrl);
                    }

                }))
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Log.e("OnFailureImageListener", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
                   
                   //some image is fails to upload 
                
                });


    }
```

so now after get `imageUriList` value from OnActivityResult we can call method by this;

```
uploadImages(new ArrayList<>(),uriFilesList);
```

and when finish to upload all image you can handle it inside

```
 private void allImageUploadedNow(ArrayList<String> imagesUrl){

  //handle imagesUrl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case of uploading multiple images into firebase I have used forEach(). forEach() method had helped me to upload images successfully into firebase

```
    import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
    const Product =()=>{
    const [file, setFile] =useState([])
    Object.values(file).forEach(val => {
    const storage = getStorage();
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'images/val.name');

    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, val);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
      (snapshot) => {
         number of bytes to be uploaded
        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
        switch (snapshot.state) {
          case 'paused':
            console.log('Upload is paused');
            break;
          case 'running':
            console.log('Upload is running');
            break;
        }
      }, 
      (error) => {
      }, 
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
          console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        });
      }
    );
    })
    return (
    <button onClick={(e) => setFile(e.target.files)}/>
    )
    }
```