# Using Firebase with Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Kotlin coroutines in my app and have chosen firebase as my choice for database and storage.
After exploring firebase I realized that all its APIs are asynchronous and the result of the asynchronous calls are returned in a callback, and getting rid of callbacks is the main reason why I am using Kotlin coroutines in my app.

This is the code I have written to upload a file to firebase cloud storage but it is giving "Task is not yet complete" error.

```
private suspend fun saveImage(filePath: String): String? {
        val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://myapp-9a648.appspot.com/")
        val storageRef = storage.reference
        val file = Uri.fromFile(File(filePath))
        val imageRef = storageRef.child("images/${file.lastPathSegment}")
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            imageRef.putFile(file).snapshot.storage.downloadUrl.result.toString()
        }
    }
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: pk.com.kotlinapp, PID: 7491
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.zzb(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source)
>           at prk.com.kotlinapptest.DatabaseManager$saveImage$2.invokeSuspend(DatabaseManager.kt:28)
>           at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)

Is there any way I can upload a file to firebase cloud storage and get back the download URL without getting the download URL in its success callback?

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services

Comment: @DougStevenson: Thanks I'll try it out.

Comment: check my answer here [upload multiple photos to firebase using kotlin coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61376574/13321079)

Answer (score 14):

`kotlinx-coroutines-play-services` [library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services) provides [await](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html) extension function that allows to await the task completion, like:

```
...
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.1"
}
```

```
return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    imageRef
        .putFile(file)
        .await() // await() instead of snapshot
        .storage
        .downloadUrl
        .await() // await the url
        .toString()
}
```

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher Yes, it does. But the question is about getting rid of callbacks. The code above is more readable I think, especially if you work with a bunch of remote calls at the same time.

Comment: For me works:
`imageRef
                .putFile(file)
                .await()
                .storage
                .downloadUrl
                .await()
                .toString()`

Comment: @Johnnie90 Thanks for the correction! I've fixed the answer.

Comment: how do you catch multiple exceptions if throw ?

Comment: Starting in [Firebase BoM 31.0.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#bom_v31-0-0), the `kotlinx-coroutines-play-services` library is already included in `firebase-storage-ktx`, so you no longer need to manually add that dependency. `await()` should be provided out of the box.