# How to upload image files to FIRESTORE using crud method?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently uploading some data to firestore:

```
 Map<String, dynamic> ads = {
                      'adTitle': widget.title,
                      'adPrice': widget.price,
                      'adCategory': widget.dropdownValue,
                      'adCondition': this.newCondtionVal,
                      'adDesc': widget.desc,
                      'user_id': uID,
                    
                      ///TODO upload the images.
                    };
                    crudObj
                        .addData(ads)
                        .then((value) => {
                              showInSnackBar("dataAdded"),
                            })
                        .catchError((e) {
                      print(e);
                    });
```

Images selected via Image_Picker, the question is how can I upload it to firebase using the method mentioned above.
PS: I'm a newbie to Flutter and Firebase stuff.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to use Firestore for image data.  Firestore documents are limited to 1MB in size, and any many images easily grow larger than that.  Cloud Storage is more suitable for images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert your image to base64 and give to the firebase which gives you the `getDownloadURL`. That `getDownloadURL` should be saved somewhere so you can access it and show it into your flutter app.

I have a code snippet which you can refer it

```
Future uploadFile() async {    
   StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance    
       .ref()    
       .child('chats/${Path.basename(_image.path)}}');    
   StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_image);    
   await uploadTask.onComplete;    
   print('File Uploaded');    
   storageReference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {    
     setState(() {    
       _uploadedFileURL = fileURL;    
     });    
   });    
 }
```

This is about a firebase real-time database. if you need for firebase database then please let me know.

Comment: I am sharing some links as well so you will get the idea that how to do it.
https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-storage-in-flutter-9f23b04291e5 and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-image-file-to-firebase-storage-using-flutter/

Comment: How can I link this image file with the details I've already uploaded? 
(Image will fall into  storage and the details(Strings) will fall into firestore)

Comment: make a document and store this string which you will get from `getDownloadURL` object along with some details like title, price etc.. using setData method of firebase

Comment: Hey, your answer was useful. could you please tell me how can I do this for firebase databse, and any ideas on how to upload multiple images?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272309/upload-multiple-images-to-firebase-storage Please refer to this one.